# jQuery pagination - Applying class to items

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, pagination

I am trying to design a pagination system in jQuery. The bit I am stuck on is when I click on different page number links, I want it to move the "active" class to the newly clicked page.

In the example page "1" has the active class. When I click "2" I want the active class to move to "2" and be removed from "1".

http://jsfiddle.net/qKyNL/24/

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 5000,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#content').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            // TO DO: Load in new content
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: '0px'
            }, 300);
            // TO DO: Change URL
            // TO DO: Set number as active class
        },
        error: function (x, t, m) {
            if (t === "timeout") {
                alert("Request timeout");
            } else {
                alert('Request error');
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#content').fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    });    
});
```

I'm quite new to jQuery and could do with some help. Can anyone please give me some guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check `addClass` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and `removeClass` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the current active li and add the active class to the one you clicked.
Add those two lines in your click event handler

```
$('#pagination li.active').removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
```